# How to display a google map route in mapview?

Tags: android

First of all, I am new to android and trying to learn new things.

I want to display a google map route in a view (probably mapview). I have some google map URLs for my routes something like this:

***removed the link***

I just want to display this route in my app. Zoom-in and zoom-out to route can be perfect.

How can I do that? I need your assistance.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I do a research and I can not find a solution to display the route from the URL.

Comment: Sorry for posting external links but [what's that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNDfD6YnJE8) or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRDLjUK8nyU)?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467062/how-to-draw-route-between-two-points-in-mapfragment-using-google-maps-android-ap

Comment: @BlindKai thanks but the links you shared are for drawing a route. My route is ready. I just want to display it.

Comment: @shubhamvashisht it is not what I want. I do not want the user enter a location. I have several routes which I shared one of them above. I just want to display it in the app.

Comment: The link you are using an internal Google Maps route. What Google provides for free with MapView is just the map engine & tiles. You are responsible for drawing any route lines. Google does have a [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) but will cost money to use.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks a lot. You mean there is no way to do it for free :( I do in a webview but it is not what I want.

Comment: You can [send the user to the full Google Maps app via an Intent with a directions request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) is another option.

Comment: thanks @MorrisonChang. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you are using an internal Google Maps route. What Google provides for free with MapView is just the map engine & tiles. You are responsible for drawing any route lines. Google does have a [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) but will cost money to use.

As a alternate, you can [send the user to the full Google Maps app via an Intent with directions request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)